# How to change a field type in a Django model with existing data?

Tags: django

I have the following existing twitter field on the extended UserProfile model and I'd like to change the field type from a URLField to a CharField with max_length of 20.  When I try to migrate the change, I get the error `django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(20)`.  I do not care about existing data in that field and prefer they go blank if there is existing data when migrating.  How can I change the field type and clear existing data?

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    # old field
    twitter = models.URLField(verbose_name="Twitter", blank=True)

    # new field
    # twitter = models.CharField(
    #     max_length=20, verbose_name="Twitter Username", null=True, blank=True
    # )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Approach 1st

In order to change to type and maximum length of a field which should know the longest url length in your db.
If you are using sqlite3 database then run the following query in your db_shell or sqlite3 shell or whatever you have.

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(column_name)) FROM table_name;
```

and then set the max_length of the **new** field to that value.

## Approach 2nd

```
python manage.py shell
```

and then

```
# Import your model
profiles = UserProfile.objects.all()
max_length = 0
for userprofile in userprofiles:
    if len(userprofile.twitter) > max_length:
        max_length = len(userprofile.twitter)
print(max_length)
```

and then set your max_length to the value printed from the above code.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that there are values on that column, that are longer than 20 characters.

You need to track and change them. **This will change them into an empty string, so existing data will be lost for good.**

```
UPDATE <table_name>
SET twitter = ""
WHERE LENGTH(twitter) > 20;
```

Then you can run you migrations.